# .Net Core Hosted Services in a Load Balanced Environment

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, asp.net-core-hosted-services

We are developing a Web API using .Net Core. To perform background tasks we have used Hosted Services.

System has been hosted in AWS Beantalk Environment with the Load Balancer. So based on the load Beanstalk creates/remove new instances of the system.

Our problem is, 
Since background services also runs inside the API, When load balancer increases the instances, number of background services also get increased and there is a possibility to execute same task multiple times. Ideally there should be only one instance of background services.

One way to tackle this is to stop executing background services when in a load balanced environment and have a dedicated non-load balanced single instance environment for background services only.

That is a bit ugly solution. So,

1) Is there a better solution for this?

2) Is there a way to identify the primary instance while in a load balanced environment? If so I can conditionally register Hosted services.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find any more information on this?

Comment: Not really. Currently what I have done is, disabling executing background services in the load-balanced environment, and have another single-instance environment for background services. I use an app-settings variable to conditionally register hosted services. I know this is an ugly solution, but its working ok so far. Using AWS Lambdas for background services would be better in this case. (are you hosting on AWS?)

Comment: My ASP.NET Core apps are hosted on IIS. I think we are going to look into using Hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io/) to solve the load balancer issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same scenario and thinking of a way to implement a custom service architecture that can run normally on all of the instance but to take advantage of pub/sub broker and distributed memory service so those small services will contact each other and coordinate what's to be done. It's complicated to develop yes but a very robust solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You'll "have to" use a distributed "lock" system. You'll have to use, for example, a distributed memory cache who put a lock when someone (a node of your cluster) is working on background. If another node is trying to do the same job, he'll be locked by the first lock if the work isn't done yet.
What i mean, if all your nodes doesn't have a "sync handler" you can't handle this kind of situation. It could be SQL app lock, distributed memory cache or other things ..

Answer (score 0):

There is something called Mutex but even that won't control this in multi-instance environment. However, there are ways to control it to some level (may be even 100%). One way would be to keep a tracker in the database. e.g. if the job has to run daily, before starting your job in the background service you might wanna query the database if there is any entry for today, if not then you will insert an entry and start your job.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).